# accessing different elements of an HTML tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button:

```
<a href="#" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ladda-button" 
data-style="contract" data-size="l">
    <span class="ladda-label">TESTLABEL</span>
</a>
```

and I'm trying to access the text inside of it: `TESTLABEL` through an IF statement.  I can change the text like this:

```
$('#form-submit').text('GO').button("refresh");
```

but this if/else statement runs the first set of code each time - never the `else if` part.

```
console.log($('#form-submit').text());

if ($('#form-submit').text('TESTLABEL')) {
    $('#form-submit').text('GO').button("refresh");
} 
else if ($('#form-submit').text('GO')) {
    //do other code...
}
```

When I click the button - the text is TESTLABEL, and that changes to GO once I click.  When I click again, the console.log tells me that this button's text is GO, but the first if statement still runs as though its text were TESTLABEL.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly the text is inside the `span` element within the `#form-submit` element, so you should use `$('#form-submit span')` or `$('#form-submit .ladda-label')` to select it.

Secondly, in your if statement you're using the setter version of the `text()` method. This will *always* equate to `true` as the method returns a jQuery object. Instead, use the getter. Try this:

```
var $button = $('#form-submit')
var $label = $button.find('span');
if ($label.text() == 'TESTLABEL') {
    $label.text('GO');
    $button.button("refresh");
} 
else if ($label.text() == 'GO') {
    //do other code...
}
```

Comment: Would the `.button("refresh")` code work if you are selecting the span now?

Comment: Interesting.  This works, but it's setting the `GO` value twice.  So the new value of the button is `GOGO`.  I can't figure out where that's occurring.